# Faster way to type whole strings instead of single chars in another window

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code where I need to type in in another Window(VFP) some strings.
I already have implemented an foreach to type in the chars but it seems to take too long for everything to be processed.

```
IntPtr hw = win32.FindWindow(null, deffensterTitel);
foreach (char c in stringToBeSent.ToCharArray())
{
    object o = new System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter().ConvertFromString(c.ToString());
    System.Windows.Forms.Keys key = (System.Windows.Forms.Keys)o;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    win32.SendKey(key, hw, false);
}
```

I could also write everything in a file to be read later on but it creates a huge risk for the other software by doing so.

Is there any other way to make it process faster or any alternative way?

Comment: You might be better off working with a higher level tool for [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) which works at a more "semantic" level than fiddling with windows and sending messages.

Comment: Also .NET has [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) built in - no need to go to native for that.

Comment: The targeted window is a VFP UI for which I don't have access to the source code and am also unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way for my use case to copy the whole string into the clipboard and paste it right on the focused form was like the following codesnippet:

```
var t = new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
{
    Clipboard.SetText(code.Trim());
}));
    
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
t.Join();
```